# Difference between A a; and A a();

Tags: c++, gcc, default-constructor

I am a newer in C++. I am just learning the C++ default constructor.
I am confused with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
            std::cout << "default constructor(no parameter)." << std::endl;
        }
        A(int a = 1, int b = 3)
        {
            std::cout << "default constructor(parameters have default value)." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << std::endl;
        }
        ~A()
        {
            std::cout << "~A" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    //A a;   // complie error: call of overloaded 'A()' is ambiguous.

    A a1();  // OK. but what does it do?

    A a2(2); // OK. call the A(int, int)
    return 0;
}
```

my GCC is 4.9.2.

- one: A() and A(int a = 1, int b = 2) are the default constructor?
- two: When I call A a1(); It outputted nothing.Why?
- three: according to the output, A a2(2) call the A(int a=1, int b=2), is that correct?

my result of this code is

```
default constructor(parameters have default value).
a:2 b:3
~A
```

`A a1()` outputted nothing???

Comment: Most vexing parse?   If it could be a declaration, it is...

Comment: Answer for your 1st and 3rd question, yes and yes.

Comment: http://ideone.com/7TrlaS for the question 2. It still call the constructor and output a line. I can't produce your error. Maybe the compiler "understand" it as declaring a function a() with return type A.

Comment: Your comment A a; is ambiguous since both your constructor can be call in this way.

Comment: according to the result, the `A a1()` didn't call the constructor. it outputted nothing. I didn't see the line
> It still call the constructor and output a line

Comment: @khôinguyễn It comes from `A a2(2);`. `A a1();` is just a function declaration.

Comment: Cool!  
I understanded it.

Comment: @khôinguyễn No, it's specified by C++ standard. If GCC 5.1 do this it'll be a bug; BTW since C++11 we prefer to write `A a1{};` instead.

Comment: I tried to use `A a{}` and complie with -std=gnu++11.Then it works.